# cakephp sha1 password saving in mysql

Tags: cakephp, sha1

I have forgot password feature in my cakephp application. The function for this will request the email address, find this user, generate a new password, convert it to sha1 and save it to the database, emailing the contents to the user.

Anyway I am having issues, the generated sha1 password is different to the one being saved.

I have called the info to the screen to show what is happening:

> **TEMP PASSWORD**- lHQcVp4  (FROM THE FUNCTION)
> Blockquote
>
> **SHA1 PASSWORD**- 0ee4ae757733f458b9e395a8457c2ef307af99f0 (FROM sha1($user['User']['tmp_password']);
>
> **Auth Password PASSWORD**- 93df9bd251620d0634235c22f4ab6fe9ad5421f4 (FROM: $this->Auth->password($user['User']['tmp_password']);)
>
> **DB Record After Save PASSWORD**- 13ef648db45cc62b593c3943646806af06846016 (FROM $this->User->field('password');)

I am saving the data as follows:  $this->User->save($user, false)

Why would it come though differently all 3 times? I cannot work it out. Very strange.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sha1($user['User']['tmp_password']
```

This will simply hash the password and output the text

```
$this->Auth->password($user['User']['tmp_password']);
```

This hashes the password **with the cakephp salt** defined in core.php. This is why you see a difference

If you simply set the password value to $user['User']['password'] and call save() on it, Auth might be hashing the password again since it doesn't know you've already hashed it. Have you tried just setting the password to $user['User']['password'] and calling save() on it? Let Auth handle the hashing for you.

Comment: Thankyou this worked. I still don't understand why the save is hashing the password but anyway thankyou for the solution.

Comment: That's how the Auth component works. If the field is named 'password' or 'passwd' it will automatically hash the password for you. More details here : http://book.cakephp.org/view/1253/Troubleshooting-Auth-Problems